# Why is my component not rerendering after form submission and setting state with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, state

I am building a component that is supposed to rerender after a form submission, and it sends the database perfectly fine, but I want the component to rerender after it submits and not having to refresh the page.

I have heard React rerenders after state is changed, and I have tried to set the state of the form inputs on submit.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import { FirebaseContext } from '../Firebase';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import AddNew from '../AddNew';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import Firebase from '../Firebase';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';
import { throwStatement, thisExpression, tsExpressionWithTypeArguments } from '@babel/types';



class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      isHidden: false,
      name: '',
      image: '',
      data: []
    }

    this.baseState = this.state

    this.toggleAddNew = this.toggleAddNew.bind(this);
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.props.firebase.getClients().then(snapshot => {
      this.setState({
        data: snapshot.docs
      })
    });
  }

  // Component lifecycle methods

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getPosts()
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('updated')
  }

  toggleAddNew() {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
  }

  updateInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  resetForm = () => {
    this.setState(this.baseState)
  }

  deletePost = (id) => {
    this.props.firebase.deleteClient(id);
  }

  addClient = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.firebase.addClient().add({
      name: this.state.name,
      image: this.state.image
    })
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      image: ''
    });
    this.resetForm();
  };


  render() {

    const renderPosts = this.state.data.map((item) => (

      <li data-id={item.id} className="client-wrapper col-sm-4">
        <button onClick={() => this.deletePost(item.id)}>X</button>
        <Link to={`/dates/${item.id}`}>
          <h2>{item.data().name}</h2>
        </Link>
        <Link to={`/dates/${item.id}`}>
          <img src={item.data().image} />
        </Link>
      </li>

    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <ul id="client-list" className="row">{renderPosts}</ul>
        <button onClick={this.toggleAddNew.bind(this)}>Add New</button>
        {this.state.isHidden ? 
        <div id="add-new-form-wrapper">
          <button onClick={this.toggleAddNew.bind(this)} id="x-add-new">X</button>
          <form onSubmit={this.addClient.bind(this)} id="add-new-form">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onChange={this.updateInput} value={this.state.name} />
            <input type="text" name="image" placeholder="Image" onChange={this.updateInput} value={this.state.image} />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div> :
          ''}
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default compose(
  withFirebase,
)(Home);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

> `this.baseState = this.state`

only makes a copy of object reference, not a copy of state object (with property values).

When we have a reference copy

> `resetForm = () => {
>       this.setState(this.baseState)
>     }`

can work like `state = state`, does nothing.

The copy of object (with current property values) can be done (f.e.) this way:

```
this.baseState = {...this.state}
```

With this small fix it should work ...

... if not, try

```
resetForm = () => {
  this.setState({...this.baseState})
}
```

You can also update some state field with current time to force rerender or simply call `this.forceUpdate()` (see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)).

BTW - `resetForm` shouldn't overwrite `data`. Luckily we have a copy of `data` object reference in `baseState` ;)